How to know when `leafletProxy` finishes rendering an updated map?
With a plain leaflet map, we can use htmlwidgets::onRender() in order to perform an action when the map finishes rendering.
When using leafletProxy() to update a map, is there any way to know when the rendering of the update finished?
Here's an example shiny app, when you press the button it adds polygons. How can I get a callback when the rendering on the client side is complete?
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(sf)

polys <- st_sf(
  geometry = st_sfc(
    st_polygon(list(rbind(
      c(-101.744384765625, 39.32155002466662),
      c(-101.5521240234375, 39.330048552942415),
      c(-101.40380859375, 39.330048552942415),
      c(-101.33239746093749, 39.364032338047984),
      c(-101.041259765625, 39.36827914916011),
      c(-100.975341796875, 39.30454987014581),
      c(-101.0399169921875, 39.24501680713314),
      c(-101.243896484375, 39.16414104768742),
      c(-101.455078125, 39.11125631228113),
      c(-101.737060546875, 39.13006024213511),
      c(-101.77825927734375, 39.16839962520706),
      c(-101.734619140625, 39.254884981213734),
      c(-101.744384765625, 39.32155002466662)
    )))
  )
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map"),
  actionButton("go", "go")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% 
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(-101, 39, 8)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    leafletProxy("map") %>%
      addPolygons(data = polys)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


What do you think about this or this answer (adding an EventListener inside the onRender on the original map)?

Thanks, I did come up with a hacky solution that does that - usingmap.on('layeradd', function() { ... }); but it's not a pretty solution so I'm looking for something better. The layeradd event gets called hundreds of times which is why it doesn't seem like the cleanest solution. It works, but I was hoping for something more explicit - a message from leafletProxy that says "not busy anymore"

@Jan you can see my answer to see why I don't like this approach

Here a posit community crosspost can be found.

I have one solution that works, but it's not very clean so I'm waiting to see if someone else has a better solution.
In this solution, I add an onRender() to the initial leaflet object and in it I add a listener to the layeradd event on the map. Whenever that event fires, I send a message to shiny that triggers an input (leaflet_complete). Because the layeradd event fires multiple times (in my real usecase it fires 100s of times) and I don't want to keep sending the input to shiny so many times, I added some code to make sure that I only trigger the event once every time that leafletProxy is invoked.
This isn't a super clean approach, I'm hopeful that there is a more explicit general signal from leafletProxy or from leaflet that says just once "I'm done".
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(sf)

polys <- st_sf(
  geometry = st_sfc(
    st_polygon(list(rbind(
      c(-101.744384765625, 39.32155002466662),
      c(-101.5521240234375, 39.330048552942415),
      c(-101.40380859375, 39.330048552942415),
      c(-101.33239746093749, 39.364032338047984),
      c(-101.041259765625, 39.36827914916011),
      c(-100.975341796875, 39.30454987014581),
      c(-101.0399169921875, 39.24501680713314),
      c(-101.243896484375, 39.16414104768742),
      c(-101.455078125, 39.11125631228113),
      c(-101.737060546875, 39.13006024213511),
      c(-101.77825927734375, 39.16839962520706),
      c(-101.734619140625, 39.254884981213734),
      c(-101.744384765625, 39.32155002466662)
    )))
  )
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(
    "let leafletComplete = false;
     Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('leafletRender', function(message) { leafletComplete = false; });"
  )),
  leafletOutput("map"),
  actionButton("go", "go")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% 
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(-101, 39, 8) %>% 
      htmlwidgets::onRender("
        function(el, x) {
          this.on('layeradd', function() {
            if (!leafletComplete) {
              leafletComplete = true;
              Shiny.setInputValue('leaflet_complete', true, {priority: 'event'});
            }
          });
        }
      ")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    session$sendCustomMessage("leafletRender", TRUE)
    leafletProxy("map") %>%
      addPolygons(data = polys)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$leaflet_complete, {
    print("complete")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

